# error: request for member … which is of non-class type

Tags: c++, pointers, compiler-errors

I understand this has something to do with my pointers but I am unsure why nor do I know how to fix it. Appreciate any help. Main is pretty crappy, I know, it is just currently being tested for the input to the array. I am not allowed to use vectors yet or this would have been a bit easier.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ToDoList.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string input;
    ToDoList List(); // <-- ERROR HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        cout << "Input 'To Do' to add to list.";
        cin >> input;
        List.AddToArray(input); // <-- ERROR HERE
    }
    List.ListArray();
    return 0;
}
```

ToDoList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "ToDoList.h"
using namespace std;

ToDoList::ToDoList() {
    array_count = 3;
    array = new string[3];
    array_count_data = 0;
}

ToDoList::ToDoList(const ToDoList& L) {
    array_count = L.array_count;
    array_count_data = L.array_count_data;
    for (int k = 0; k < array_count; k++)
        array[k] = L.array[k];
}

ToDoList::~ToDoList() {
    delete []array;
}

void ToDoList::AddToArray(string input){
    if (array_count == array_count_data){
            string * upsize_array = new string[array_count + 1];
            for(int i = 0; i < array_count; i++)
                upsize_array[i] = array[i];
            delete [] array;
            array_count++;
            this->array[array_count];
            for(int i = 0; i < array_count; i++)
                array[i] = upsize_array[i];
            delete [] upsize_array;
        }
        array[array_count_data] = input;
        array_count_data++;
}

void ToDoList::ListArray(){
    for(int j = 0; j < array_count_data; j++){
        cout << array[j] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings. I know at least Clang gives a nice clear message for this.

Comment: `ToDoList List();` That's a function declaration.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: main.cpp:28:14: error: request for member ‘AddToArray’ in ‘List’, which is of non-class type ‘ToDoList()’
main.cpp:30:10: error: request for member ‘ListArray’ in ‘List’, which is of non-class type ‘ToDoList()'

These are the two errors.

Comment: @user3047909 jrok already pointed out the problem, try remove the `()` after `List`.

Comment: Okay, I feel incredibly stupid. Thanks for pointing that out. I would have stared at this for another hour before I found that. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Not stupid. It's called "the most vexing parse" because it catches everybody out, sooner or later.